# Switching users in a remote PC with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, windows-7, logoff

So as the title self implies I'm trying to put together a PowerShell script so I can switch the user of multiple computers, from the primary server which is connected to all of them.

Currently, all devices have two users.

1. Application
2. Admin

By default, all computers are in the **application** user. So the idea is to have a **TXT** list, which would determine which ones to log off/sign in into the **Admin** user account.

Currently I'm using:

```
foreach ($_ in get-content .\CPUNameList.txt) 
{(gwmi win32_operatingsystem -ComputerName $_).Win32Shutdown(4)}
```

Which grabs from CPUNameList.txt, and logs off the stations. It works to log a bunch of them off, but i still need to go and log them all in.

Assuming the credentials for **Admin** is say,

**User:** Admin
**Pass:** PASSWORD

How would we even go about doing this..?

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with:

```
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString "PASSWORD" -AsPlainText -Force
$mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("Admin", $secpasswd)

foreach ($_ in get-content .\CPUNameList.txt)
    {New-PSSession -ComputerName $computername -Credential $mycreds}
```

See [technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh849717.aspx) and [ss64](http://ss64.com/ps/new-pssession.html) for more

Comment: Appreciate the help! Looks like i'm having some errors with this..its showing this error: `ConvertTo-SecureString : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'string' because it is an empty string.` --- any thoughts? I'm entering the appropiate password as well as user.

Comment: Not at my PC now but it looks like it thinks the string parameter is empty, did you try adding `-string` in front of "password"?